# Changing JS code to work with other elements - HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, custom-element

If I have the following JS code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function() {

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
```

This is the HTML:

```html
<a href="#about">
  <div class="containerScroll">
    <div class="first-scroll"></div>
    <div class="second-scroll"></div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Right now the scrolling effect is working for all links with the tag `a`; however, can I change the `$("a").on('click', function(event) {` to something like `$("scroll").on('click', function(event) {`? Now, I'm hoping it will work for all the tags with `scroll` so now my HTML would look like:

```html
<scroll href="#about">
  <div class="containerScroll">
    <div class="first-scroll"></div>
    <div class="second-scroll"></div>
  </div>
</scroll>
```

Would this work? Essentially, I want to add another tag instead of `a` because I do not want the scrolling effect to take place on **all** the links and only the ones I choose. This is why I tried changing the tag to `scroll` but it still did not work? Am I supposed to define a `scroll` css property for it to work?

Comment: There is no native `<scroll/>` element in HTML, as far as I am aware.  Are you attempting to define a custom element/web component?  Or is there perhaps some understanding on how HTML works here?

Comment: I'm attempting to define a custom element

Comment: For me to use `<scroll/>` what css property should `scroll` have?

Comment: The only elements that have a `hash` property are `<a>`

Comment: Custom elements _must have a hyphen in the tag name_. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#valid-custom-element-name

Comment: Not to discourage you necessarily, but what is the reason you are trying to use a custom element here?  Are you intending on imbuing it with unique functionality?  Have you considered the accessibility implications or replacing anchors with custom elements?

Comment: @charlietfl I'm pretty sure a custom element can too, no?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I guess you could define one, was only thinking native elements

Comment: In what way is this failing to work for you?  I attempted to use a simplified version of your code and was able to get an event listener on a `<scroll/>` element.  Are you seeing no result on clicking?  Broken behavior?  Console errors?  You should provide a [mcve] with enough context to reproduce the problem, as well as the steps to reproduce, the desired behavior, and the actual behavior.  As it is, I think there is too little information for anyone to provide you with meaningful guidance.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery for smooth scrolling is pointless nowadays

There are two methods (#2 is better IMO)

```
const element = document.querySelector('#something')
// element is the target you're trying to scroll to
```

1. JS Method- Works just for the element you've selected

```
element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" })
```

2. CSS Method

```
/* in CSS */
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```
//in JS
element.scrollIntoView()
```